# Mapnik v2.3.0 under IIS crashes the AppPool

Tags: postgresql, iis, openstreetmap, application-pool, mapnik

I'm running Mapnik under IIS (Windows x32) to create OSM tiles from PostgreSQL. However, after a few seconds / minuets, the AppPool crashes with no explanation (Event Viewer gives no meaningful error). Neither WinDBG etc' to capture the AppPool crash.

Have you ever tried to run Mapnik under IIS? 
Any idea what might cause the crash?

TIA,
Yaniv

Answer (score 0):

We are trying to use Mapnik as a render engine for WMS. To do that we register mapnik data sources from  /mapnik/input         and fonts from /mapnik/fonts.

We use agg_renderer to render the image into image_32, then the image_32 saved to a buffer (with save_to_string). This process is done through critical section, so Mapnik is not called concurrently.
When this code is called from an executable, the data is rendered correctly, with no crashed. However, when the same code is called from IIS, the app pool crashes very frequently.

we use 32 bit app pool.

Thank you very much, 
Yaniv